# how to access Thingsboard Internal database?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm creating a IoT fleet tracking system using Thingsboard.. I have little knowledge in IoT since it's my first time. My problem is -i can't access the thingsboard internal storage of raw data. if anyone can asnwer me, it would be a great help for my project.

Comment: Almost all of thingsboards internals are exposed through apis. Why don’t you take the api route ?

Answer (score 4):

Thingsboard supports several database backends (HSQLDB, Cassandra and PostgreSQL as of Thingsboard 1.4). HSQLDB is the default for test installs, so I assume that's what you are using.

1. Install sqltool. On Ubuntu/Debian this is done with the command

> sudo apt-get install hsqldb-utils

2. Create ~/sqltool.rc with the following contents:

> urlid thingsboard
>
> url jdbc:hsqldb:file:/usr/share/thingsboard/data/sql/thingsboardDb;shutdown=true
>
> username SA
>
> password

3. Start sqltool (you'll need to stop Thingsboard first using *service thingsboard stop*):

> hsqldb-sqltool thingsboard

4. To list tables, type \dt
5. Perform sql queries the same way you would do through any other SQL command line interface.
6. Exit with \q

Comment: don't forget to stop thingsboard service otherwise it cannot acquire the lock.

Comment: I try this and `Error: Could not find or load main class org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool`